# Core dump on Pointer type-casting (int to double) in C

Tags: c

I came across this piece of code:

```
void incme(double *p)
{
    *p += 1;
}

int i = 1;
incme((double *)&i);    /* WRONG */
```

When I try to execute it, I get core dump. What is wrong with this code. Can we not type cast an int pointer to a double type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not casting an `int` to a `double`, you're casting an `int *` to a `double *`.  That's not safe if `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(int)` aren't the same...

Even if you match up the storage sizes, what do you expect the output to be?  Floating-point types and integers tend not to have any kind of compatible representations.

Answer (score 3):

`(int)` is usually aligned to 4 bytes on 32-bit hardware, while `(double)` usually needs to be 8-byte aligned.  If your `i` isn't on an 8-byte aligned address, you can expect `SIGBUS`; also, if it's allocated on the stack, the larger `(double)` is likely to overwrite the call frame leading to a core dump when `incme()` returns, if the preceding doesn't kill it.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast any pointer from one type to any other type, but that does not make it correct. In this case if sizeof(double) != sizeof(int) then line in "incme" will most probably write to memory outside of that allocated to the "i" integer. All bets are off then.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between type *conversion* and memory *reinterpretation*.

Your code forcefully converts a pointer of `int *` type to `double *` type. That is achieved by using an explicit cast. This action alone does not necessarily lead to any problems by itself. So, the assumption that you made in the title of your question is incorrect. The "core dump" you observe has nothing to do with the cast itself.

Once you performed the conversion you proceed to dereference the resultant pointer and access (modify) the memory it points to. That's when the real problem takes place. The code performs data *reinterpretation*: it attempts to access an object of type `int` as an object of type `double`. This is always explicitly illegal in C language. The crash you observe is caused specifically by this reinterpretation attempt.

So, the short answer to your question is: You *can* certainly cast a pointer that points to an `int` object to `double *` type. But you *cannot* dereference the resultant `double *` pointer and access the memory as if it holds a `double` object.

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms, double is 8 bytes, and int 4, therefore no you can not cast int* to double* and use it

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
int i = 1;
double d1 = (double)i;
double *d = &d1;
incme(d);
```