# Platform independant cast from int to double in C (avoid SIGBUS)

Tags: c, type-conversion, primitive-types

I am not very fluent in C to start - this sounds like something trivial and obvious but despite googling it I haven't found anything else in pure C than the usual

```
double theDouble = (double) theInt;
```

This works fine on my Windows 64 bit computer, but on a 32 bit UNIX system (Android) I get a SIGBUS on this line. Is there not a nice platform independant way to convert this int to a double (I am looking to perform a real division)

Here is a full extract of the code:

```
int *rat;
BYTE *prm;
// blah blah some assignment is done on prm
rat = (int*)prm;  //For RATIONAL decoding
prm = (BYTE*)&iOffset;
double rat0= (double)rat[0]; // SIGBUS here on the cast, only on the Android device not on Windows
```

I believe this is caused by different alloc sizes for double and int on the Android system unless I am missing something. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359066/core-dump-on-pointer-type-casting-int-to-double-in-c) seems to suggest that it is something I shouldn't be doing, but surely this is a valid use case?

Comment: Where have you assigned an `int` value? I would use the simple `int i = 1; double d = i;` which might generate a compiler warning about loss of significance if `int` is 64 bits.

Comment: Please read about memory allocation.

Comment: Converting an `int` variable to a `double` value is automatic and happens implicitly, you don't need an explicit cast. It will also not cause a crash unless you use pointers which are not valid.

Comment: SIGBUS is a result of accessing invalid memory - it's most commonly a result of accessing data in a memory mapped file beyond bounds of that file.   It has nothing to do with converting an integral value to `double`.    If the symptom occurs on such an initialisation, that's probably because `theInt` no longer exists (e.g. the memory it occupies no longer exists as far as the program is concerned).

Comment: `&iOffset;` is not properly alligned for an int or double. (the intention of the above code is not very clear anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some systems require that `int` objects lie on a particular byte boundary. Your `prm` pointer may not be on such a boundary. Use `memcpy` into a proper `int` variable, then assign to your `double`.

```
int temp;
BYTE *rat = prm;
prm = (BYTE*)&iOffset;
memcpy(&temp, rat, sizeof(temp));
double rat0 = temp;
```

Comment: Consider [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error#Unaligned_access) and [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html).